# How could I make a power bar gradually fill up and go back down?

Tags: java, swing

I want to set up a dynamic casting bar that goes up and down while the mouse is being held for my fishing game project. What should I use/do to implement it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think you need to be more specific to receive a useful answer from the SO community. For example, is the problem about recording mouse button hold or displaying the bar itself?

Comment: Thanks! And yeah its just that I can't figure out how to display something that keeps going up and down on a loop.

Answer (score 4):

You could add a `MouseListener` to your component.

In the `mousePressed` event you would start a `Swing Timer`. Every time the Timer fires you change the value of your "power bar" and repaint the component. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

In the `mouseRelesed` event you stop the Timer.